# Unit Testing AngularJS Directive that uses ng-switch

Tags: angularjs

I want to unit test my directive. Here is the code:

```
.directive('getData', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: { myData:'@myData' },
        template: '<div ng-switch="myData">' +
                    '<div ng-switch-when="4">Real Data</div>' +
                    '<div ng-switch-when="5">False Data</div>' +
                    '<div ng-switch-default>No Data</div>' +
                  '</div>'
    }
```

Here is my attempt for unit testing:

```
describe('Testing', function() {

  var $compile, $rootScope;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));


    it('get some data', function() {
        var c = $compile("<get-data></get-data>")($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect(c.html()).toContain(''); //don't know how to do this part
    });
```

});

I don't know how to test ng-switch. I feel like I am missing a lots of things here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/kgygmzXT3eUMw1iNWnwP?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Directive**

```
app.directive('getData', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E,C', // Added E so <get-data></get-data> works
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            myData: '@' // Removed @myData since it's not needed here
        },
        template: '<div ng-switch on="myData">' + 
                  '  <div ng-switch-when="4">Real Data</div>' + 
                  '  <div ng-switch-when="5">False Data</div>' + 
                  '  <div ng-switch-default class="grid">No Data</div>' + 
                  '</div>'
    }
});
```

**Tests**

```
describe('get-data test', function() {
  var $scope,
      $compile;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('plunker');

    inject(function($rootScope, _$compile_) {
      $scope = $rootScope.$new();
      $compile = _$compile_;
    });
  });             

  it('renders Real Data when my-data is 4', function() {
    // Arrange
    var element = $compile('<get-data my-data="4"></get-data>')($scope);

    // Act
    element.scope().$digest();

    // Assert
    expect(element.find('div').html()).toBe('Real Data');
  });

  // Other tests omitted for brevity's sake
});
```

Check out this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aXM8PLkpaORBS641gNAp?p=preview) to see the other tests.

Notice that in order for the directive to render its markup, a digest cycle must occur in the directive's scope. To do that, you need to use `element.scope()` to get to that scope and call `$digest` on it.

Finally, since testing directives is almost all about checking if the DOM is being correctly manipulated I recommend adding jQuery as a dependency of your tests so you can take advantage of its selectors. It wasn't needed here, but it can save you a lot of time as your directive becomes more complex.

Comment: Hi Micheal, I am using angularjs 1.0.6. For this version, only the third test case worked, not the first two (kept saying expected 'Real Data' and 'False Data' to be 'No Data'). But all the three test cases are working on the later versions. I am trying to make the other two test cases('Real Data' & 'False Data') work in 1.0.6 as well. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I've done some tests and figured out a way to make it work with version 1.0.6. I've replaced `my-data="4"' with 'my-data="{{4}}"` and `element.scope().$digest()` with `$scope.$digest()` and everything is working now. I've updated the Plunker script as well.